# viewpager wrong item position pageradapter

Tags: java, android

The `instantiateItem` on the `PagerAdapter` of the `viewpager` sends the wrong item position to the activity called with the intent. When I click on image 1, it sends the info of image 2, and when i click on image 2, it sends info of image 3, and so on. The receiver activity receives the wrong image and title for the clicked on sender activity. I'm using a `floatingActionButton` with an `onclickListener` to detect the click.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View slideLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_item, null);

    final ImageView slideImg = slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_img);
    final TextView slideText = slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_title);
    final  FloatingActionButton fab = slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

    slideImg.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getImage());
    slideText.setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());
    slideTitle = slideText.getText().toString();
    thumbnail = mList.get(position).getImage();

    container.addView(slideLayout);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,  MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", slideTitle);
            intent.putExtra("imgURL", thumbnail);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);    
        }
    });

    return slideLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override this method to get current position of a fragment. use this position to get information about the current click.

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    Log.i(TAG, "setPrimaryItem: " + position);

    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code from Vishrut Mavani works pefectly
The final code gets this way

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View slideLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_item, null);

    final ImageView slideImg = slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_img);
    final TextView slideText = slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_title);
    final  FloatingActionButton fab = slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

    slideImg.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getImage());
    slideText.setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());

    container.addView(slideLayout);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", slideTitle);
            intent.putExtra("imgURL", thumbnail);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);



        }
    });

    return slideLayout;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

    container.removeView((View)object);
}
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){

    Log.i(TAG, "setPrimaryItem_che: " + position);

    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

    slideTitle = mList.get(position).getTitle();
    thumbnail = mList.get(position).getImage();
}
```